# How to calculate the number of node if the height of a complete binary tree is N.....A.2^n B.2^n-1 c.2^(n+1)-1 D. N

Tags: tree, binary-tree

If the height of a complete binary tree is n, then How many Node in the tree have.
A.2^n   B.2^n-1  c.2^(n+1)-1  D. N

Please Explain regarding the answer.....

Comment: It's quite easy to write out the sequence and work out the formula.

Answer (score 1):

It's a large range.

The minimum is N, given you can have a single node on each level.
The maximum, if every level has two nodes, is N ^ 2 - 1.

Answer (score 0):

Because the last level could be not full, you cannot give an exact number. But you could give an interval. Let N the number of nodes of a complete tree and n its height. Then

1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(n-2) < N <= 1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(n-2) + 2^(n-1)